# Facebook js SDK send with ajax variabiles to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

First of all thank you for your atention.
What I would like is to use the Facebook js SDK to get the user's name and id and send them to php in the same page (index.php). I manage to get the username and id and save them in 2 variables in JS (js_fb_id  and js_fb_name), but when I try to make the ajax call and sent them to php, nothing happens.

So, on my index.php i have the ajax script

```
            var js_fb_id = response.id; 
            var js_fb_name = response.name; //this variables are set after the user is loged in
                $.post( 'index.php', 
                    {
                    php_fb_id: js_fb_id,
                    php_fb_id: js_fb_name
                    },

                function (data){

                     console.log(data);
                }
            )
```

Later on,  I want to get the variables send via AJAX

```
        <?php if ( isset( $_POST['php_fb_id'] ) ) {
                echo $_POST['php_fb_id'];
            }
        ?>
```

Is this possible? It works when I use a separate page to make the AJAX call, but I cannot get the php variables from there to my index.php page.

Thank you

Comment: _“What I would like is to use the Facebook js SDK to get the user's name and id and send them to php”_ – no, you don’t want that - because that is easy to fake, anyone could send whatever name and id to your PHP script. What you want to do, is send only the access token to the server, and then make an API call to get name and id on the server side.

Comment: Well, if I have the fb login button from the js SDK. It is possible to submit from there any other information rather the one that you've logged in?

Comment: There is no “from there,” _anyone_ can send arbitrary requests to your index.php, not even necessarily using a browser.

Comment: auch...and how can I avoid that?

Comment: By doing what I already said you should do - send the token, and use it to make API requests on the server-side. (You might want to debug the token first, to verify it is actually a token that was issued for your app, and not a different one. How to do that, is described in the docs.)

Answer (score 1):

So basically what is happening here is that the ajax script is triggered on page load. 
However this is only after the dom has already been rendered. 
To fix this you will need to trigger the ajax function on a specific event , for eg: button click.

Also note that since your entire page is in html you ajax function is returning the entire page as 'data' and not spacifically the php variables that you are trying to set.(You will be able to see this in the console)

Also note that if you want to print the values on the page you will have to modify the html in the callback function through ajax for eg:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#post').click(function() {

      $.post( 'text.php', 
                    {
                    php_fb_id: js_fb_id,
                    php_fb_name: js_fb_name
                    },

                function (data, status){

                 $("#txt").html(data); //you can print returned data 
                     console.log(data);
                }
            ) 

  });
});
```

This should go in a separate php file say text.php

```
<?php 
    if ( isset( $_POST['php_fb_id'] ) ) {
                echo $id = $_POST['php_fb_id'];
            }

?>
```

Comment: Hi, I've made an event click. 
On index.php i have the html:
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
<button id="post">Click</button>
My new js script: 
$( '#post' ).click(function() {
      
     $.post( 'index.php', 
                    {
                    php_fb_id: js_fb_id2,
                    php_fb_name: js_fb_name2
                    },

                function (data, status){
      $("body").html(data);
                   //  console.log(data);
                }
            ) 
   
  })

Comment: Just to clarify, since php is server side you will not be able to set a php variable from a js variable on the same page.
What would be a best practice is separating your php function which fetches the js variable in a separate file and then sending it back to the original page where you can use it as you wish.
At present if you console your data returned through ajax you will notice that it returns the entire html of the page since ajax will return all printed data as a response.

Comment: thanks for clearing that out. I've made on a different page and it works

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, except that you passing php_fb_id twice in the parameter.

```
$.post( 'index.php', {
   php_fb_id: js_fb_id,
  php_fb_id: js_fb_name
},
```

Except this, parameter are passing into index.php and getting captured too. so you can go ahead with php operation there. Do let me know what is the problem you facing in this code? will definitely try to help

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your interes. Sorry, I've seen that the php_fb_id is twice after i submitted the question.
Unfortunate, it does not work. I've made an event click on a button to make the ajax call, but the variables are not passed to php. Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ez1t6cyy/
What am I doing wrong? My ajax skills are kind of rusted

Comment: Hi. Did you try hard coding the value instead of variables? is that worked?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by that. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: If that works by hard coding values and make ajax request, then your ajax call works perfectly. If not then it concludes that variables are not assigned with values that are returned by facebook(either values are null or undefined). Do perform this test condition and proceed

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { //check if it's Post request
    if( isset( $_POST['php_fb_id']  && isset( $_POST['php_fb_name']) {
        $name = $_POST['php_fb_name'];
        $id = $_POST['php_fb_id'];
        ....
        echo "OK";
    }else{
        echo "ERROR, need input";
    }
else{
    //Your Index Code Here
}
```